# setInterval + jQuery CSS Animation on Window Size

Tags: jquery, css, animation, setinterval, window-resize

I'm trying to fix this problem, I've tried all kind of ways and although logically it should work, it just doesn't. Any help would be great as I'm not that good in coding.

So I'm trying to animate a object from the left side to the end of the right side. And the positioning differs depending on the screen size.

This is so far what I've got. I'm detecting the user's browser size but I want do also destroy the setIntervals whenever thats a new resize detection.

```
showViewportSize();
var $box = $('#box');

$(window).resize(function (e) {
    window.clearInterval('animation');
    showViewportSize();
});

function showViewportSize() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();

    if (width <= 1024) {
        var box = setInterval(function () {
            $box.animate({
                "left": "+1200"
            }, 40000, function () {
                $box.removeAttr("style");
            });
        }, 400);
    }

    if ((width <= 1440) && (width > 1025)) {
        var box = setInterval(function () {
            $box.animate({
                "left": "+1200"
            }, 40000, function () {
                $box.removeAttr("style");
            });
        }, 400);
    }

    if (width >= 2000) {
        var box = setInterval(function () {
            $box.animate({
                "left": "+1200"
            }, 40000, function () {
                $box.removeAttr("style");
            });
        }, 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Just destroying the setIntervals? To do that just store the value that `setInterval` returns in a global variable (not a local `var box`) as now, and call `clearInterval` on it.

Comment: In addition to my CSS3 solution below, your issue may be that your showViewportSize() function is getting called on every iteration of the resize. What is the current behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

How about a CSS3 transition mixed with good 'ol media queries?

```
#box {
    left: 0;

    -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (min-width : 1024px) {
    #box {
        left: 1200px;
    }
}
```

Should work but haven't tested.